# Detect OS in Vimscript

Tags: vimscript

Can I retrieve the current operating system (Windows, Linux, OS X, ..) using *pure* Vimscript (no Python or Perl)?

I want to enable different settings in my (synchronized) *.vimrc* for different types of operation systems I am using.

Comment: Could you provide some specific examples of OS-dependent behaviours that you seek to implement?

Comment: @200_success I have some scripts and key bindings for [MS TFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server) and msbuild that are pretty useless in non-Windows environments, while I don't need [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) support in gVim on Windows. In addition, there are different fonts installed on different systems, and paths may differ as well.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The best way is to use [`has()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#has%28%29), with
this function you can check for features of Vim; OS specific features from
[`:help feature-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#feature-list):

```
macunix                 Macintosh version of Vim, using Unix files (OS-X).
unix                    Unix version of Vim.
win32                   Win32 version of Vim (MS-Windows 95 and later, 32 or
                        64 bits)
win32unix               Win32 version of Vim, using Unix files (Cygwin)
```

And some older (semi-deprecated) systems:

```
amiga                   Amiga version of Vim.
os2                     OS/2 version of Vim.
win16                   Win16 version of Vim (MS-Windows 3.1).
win64                   Win64 version of Vim (MS-Windows 64 bit).
win95                   Win32 version for MS-Windows 95/98/ME.
```

Example:

```
if has('win32')
    echo "Someone please open the Window(s)!"
endif
```

An alternative way with more flexibility is to call the external `uname`, this
also allows you to get the version number and such:

```
let uname = system('uname -a')
```

Note that `uname` isn't present on most Windows systems.

It's generally best to use *feature detection*, rather than *OS detection*. For example by using one of the features in `has()` or checking if some path exists. [200_success' post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2575/51) gives a good overview of that, so I'll not repeat the same content here.

Comment: Very important to note [romainl's answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2577/343) if you want it to work on OS X, though.

Comment: +1 for pointer to `:h feature-list`

Answer (score 39):

`has()` sounds like a good idea until you try it on Mac OS X: in the default `/usr/bin/vim`, `has('unix')` is *true* but both `has('macunix')` and `has('mac')` are *false* while, in the regular MacVim download, all three are *true* whether you use the GUI or the TUI.

So the best solution is a mix of `has('winXX')` for Windows and `uname` on unix-like systems. Note that the output of `uname` ends with a newline so it must be cleaned before use.

Here is the code I've been using for a while, updated for `win64`:

```
if !exists("g:os")
    if has("win64") || has("win32") || has("win16")
        let g:os = "Windows"
    else
        let g:os = substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
    endif
endif
```

After that, you can use the `g:os` variable anywhere in your `vimrc`:

```
if has("gui_running")
    if g:os == "Darwin"
        set guifont=Fira\ Mono:h12
    elseif g:os == "Linux"
        set guifont=Fira\ Mono\ 10
    elseif g:os == "Windows"
        set guifont=Fira_Mono:h12:cANSI
    endif
endif
```

Comment: Well, OSX is a UNIX system, I believe it's even "certified UNIX". So `has('unix')` is accurate. It's odd that `has('macunix')` is false, though. This almost sounds like a bug?

Comment: I did some checking, and `has('macunix')` seems to depend on `MACOS_X_UNIX`, which is set if `uname` is `Darwin` in the `configure` script...

Comment: Oddly enough, `has ("win32")` seems to work for me even in 64-bit Vim.

Comment: @Rich Yes, and that's documented as such. This is really the sane thing to do, do you care if your app is 32 or 64 bits? I don't. The reason it's called 'win32', is because that's the name Microsoft choose for their Windows NT API. [Naming things isn't Microsoft's strong point](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4039054/660921).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I agree it makes sense from pragmatism. If the documentation is using Win32 to mean "Windows API", though, what does it (and romainl) mean when it refers to "Win64"?

Comment: @Rich This is also in the documentation: *"Win64 version of Vim (MS-Windows 64 bit)."*...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I'm looking at the documentation. What I can't figure out is how you're interpreting it. To me, it's saying that win32 will be set on 32-bit Vim (regardless of what version of Windows it's running under), and that win64 will be set in 64-bit Vim. You're saying it means something different, but I can't figure out what.

Comment: `has('unix')` is also true on Windows Git Bash, so it's not very useful for distinguishing real unix from emulated.

Comment: @wisbucky why would you want to distinguish emulated unix? The emulator means to be compatible in the first place.

Comment: What is the purpose to use `if !exists("g:os")` in the very beginning?

Comment: @user90726, it is there to prevent the code from running each time you source your `vimrc`. It is not strictly necessary for the code to work.

Answer (score 8):

Environment variables would be useful.

To detect `tmux`, you could check `if !empty($TMUX)` or `if $TERM == 'screen'`.

You can also deduce the operating system from environment variables such as `$MACHTYPE` ([which is set by Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Variables)) or `$PATH`.

To detect whether a feature such as TFS is installed, you can use the [`executable()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#executable%28%29) function.

Comment: _"$MACHTYPE (which is set by Bash)"_. Actually, if a variable is set by Bash, that means it is not an environment variable, and you will not be able to access it in vim simply with `$MACHTYPE`. You will have to do something like `let machtype=system('echo -n $MACHTYPE')` first.

Answer (score 5):

As others have already indicated, a reliable detection can be tricky. Better not reinvent the wheel, so I'd like to mention the [vim-misc library](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4597), which provides `xolox#misc#os#is_mac()` and `xolox#misc#os#is_win()` functions.

Answer (score 3):

I tried `has('unix')`, but I didn't find it helpful since all my Linux, Mac, and Windows Git Bash returned `true` for it.

I found `uname` to be suitable as it distinguishes between Linux, Mac, Windows, without too much granularity.

```
let uname = substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
" Example values: Linux, Darwin, MINGW64_NT-10.0, MINGW32_NT-6.1

if uname == 'Linux' || uname == 'Darwin'
    " do linux/mac command
else " windows
    " do windows command
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this on my vimscript, currently on Vim v8.0:

```
if has("mac")
    "Mac
elseif has("win32")
    "all Windows, ie win32,win64
elseif has("win32unix")
    "Cygwin
elseif has("bsd")
    "BSD-based, ie freeBSD"
elseif has("linux")
    "Linux
end
```

This covers most of the OS, I hope.  One should use `has(feature)` if possible, and avoid `uname`, since `uname` is not portable (ie not available on non-unix-like OS)