# has('mac') returns 0, but I'm on a mac?

Tags: macvim, macos

I am using vim in a terminal on my mac.

I understand that the command:

```
echo has('mac')
```

should return `1` (it does on macvim), because it's running on a mac. But it returns `0`. Can anyone tell me why this is, and if there's a more reliable way of detecting if vim is running on osx?

EDIT: `:echo has('macunix')` also returns `0`

EDIT2: `:echo has('osx')` also returns `0`

Comment: try  `has('macunix')`

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt I meant to add that, thanks for the reminder

Comment: `echo has('osx')` ?

Comment: See the second answer, by romainl, here: [Detect OS in Vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/detect-os-in-vimscript). You need to use `uname`.