# How can I detect if the vim I'm running on is the Git for Windows vim?

Tags: terminal, microsoft-windows, git

I have a shared `.vimrc` that I use across platforms. It works fine in most circumstances, but looks terrible when I run `git commit` from the command line. I want to make my color scheme not load when run in that circumstance, but the conventional test for windows `has("win32")` fails in that environment! In fact, `has("unix")` is true in that environment!

**Does anyone know what configuration of Vim is shipped with Git for Windows, and how to detect it?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect OS in Vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2572/detect-os-in-vimscript)

Comment: See specifically the second answer

Comment: maybe check `has("win32unix")` or perhaps check some environment variables

Comment: I'm inclined to close based on @Zoe's comment, since one answer there specifically addresses this. Sean, if you can confirm/deny (an [edit] or comment is fine) that it answers your question, I'll do so. I'm holding off otherwise.

Comment: @Zoe Just FYI "second answer" can mean different things to different people depending on how they've chosen to sort their answers! If you want to link a specific answer click the `Share` link found below it. :)

Comment: @BLayer Right, my bad ^^" I never use any other sorting orders than votes - easy to forget it exists. I was referring to [this one](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2577/21251)

Comment: @Zoe, No, because git vim doesn't trigger has("win32").

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Oh, git vim does trigger has("win32unix"). please make that an answer so I can pick it!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: user [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt) points out that `v:progpath` will still only contain `/usr/bin/vim` when invoked through git-for-windows, so this solution will not work.

---

Maybe something along these lines?

```
if v:progpath =~ "git"
    colorscheme default
endif
```

The variable `v:progpath` should contain a path to the running vim executable, and (assuming that the version of vim that `git commit` spawns is included in your git installation) `=~ "git"` should detect whether that executable is within git's installation directory. (This is all very hypothetical of course)

According to `help v:progpath`:

> ```
> v:progpath    Contains the command with which Vim was invoked, in a form
>       that when passed to the shell will run the same Vim executable
>       as the current one (if $PATH remains unchanged).
>       Useful if you want to message a Vim server using a
>       |--remote-expr|.
>       To get the full path use: 
>           echo exepath(v:progpath)
>       If the command has a relative path it will be expanded to the
>       full path, so that it still works after `:cd`. Thus starting
>       "./vim" results in "/home/user/path/to/vim/src/vim".
>       On Linux and other systems it will always be the full path.
>       On Mac it may just be "vim" and using exepath() as mentioned
>       above should be used to get the full path.
>       On MS-Windows the executable may be called "vim.exe", but the
>       ".exe" is not added to v:progpath.
>       Read-only.
> ```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This could benefit from some explanation, esp. the `v:progpath` variable (citing the help is fine!). For example, does `v:progpath` usually contain `git` when vim is started by `git-commit` on Windows? Is that reliable?

Comment: `v:progpath` is the path to the actual running vim instance. In Git-For-Windows, this is something like `/usr/bin/vim`. It has nothing to do with git itself, just that git-for-windows packages vim along with many other POSIX like utilities.

Answer (score 1):

A new angle of attack:

```
if has_key(environ(), "MINGW_PREFIX") && has_key(environ(), "GIT_INDEX_FILE")
    colorscheme default
endif
```

Poking around in `help environ`, it looks like `has_key(environ(), <name>)` is the recommended way of determining whether a system environment variable is defined. I'm not an expert on what variables will or won't exist during `git commit`, but `MINGW_PREFIX` *looks* like its an artifact of the unix compatibility layer git-for-windows uses (worth a google), and `GIT_INDEX_FILE` *looks* like its provided by `git` itself (per [the docs](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables)). Again, highly theoretical, YMMV!