# Conversion in Lua: Detect OS in Vimscript

Tags: neovim, init.lua, init.vim

Related to this post, [Detect OS in Vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2577/36876)

This configuration detects and sets the operating system in Vim. It uses conditional statements to determine if the OS is Windows or Unix-like.

```
if !exists("g:os")
    if has("win64") || has("win32") || has("win16")
        let g:os = "Windows"
    else
        let g:os = substitute(system('uname'), '\n', '', '')
    endif
endif
```

Is there a more efficient or elegant way to achieve this in Lua?

PS: I'm a newbie at this. This is my first try. Please let me know if it needs any fix.

```lua
if not vim.g.os then
    local is_windows = vim.fn.has("win64") or vim.fn.has("win32") or vim.fn.has("win16")
    if is_windows then
        vim.g.os = "Windows"
    else
        local uname_output = vim.fn.system('uname')
        vim.g.os = string.gsub(uname_output, '\n', '')
    end
end
```

There's a bug. This code shows `Windows` in my `fedora` system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do:

```lua
if vim.fn.exists('g:os') == 0 then
    local is_windows = vim.fn.has("win64") == 1 or vim.fn.has("win32") == 1 or vim.fn.has("win16") == 1
    if is_windows then
        vim.g.os = "Windows"
    else
        local uname_output = vim.fn.system('uname')
        vim.g.os = string.gsub(uname_output, '\n', '')
    end
end
```

But I have tested your code and with Neovim 9.2 in the absence of the `g:os` variable it seems to work fine too.

Comment: The code seems fine. I still haven't figured out this code output. I'm on fedora. How to test this? Can you tell me?

Comment: This code is setting the `g:os` variable I suppose on Fedora it should set it to `Linux` (at least it what it does on Ubuntu). On Windows it set it to `Windows`. You can verify the variable value with the command `:echo g:os`

Comment: Showing error `E121: Undefined variable: g:os`

Comment: My bad I have corrected the answer :-|

Comment: I have tested on Ubuntu and this code is working (I was confused that in Lua 0 is true).

Comment: OMG, It is working.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :-)